# Template class method specialization fails when type is a pointer

Tags: c++

I have a template class called Vector and I want to specialize one of its methods called my_compare depending on the type that the class takes in. I am able to successfully specialize it for most types, however the specialization will not compile if I am using a pointer type.

At top of cpp file:

```
template <typename T> class Vector {
public: 
...
  bool my_compare(const T a, const T b);
...
};
```

Later on:

```
template <typename T> bool Vector<T>::my_compare(const T a, const T b){
  return (a < b);
}
template <> bool Vector<Mystring>::my_compare(const Mystring a, const Mystring b){
  //cout << "did a mycompare for stringies";
  return (strcmp(a.c_str(), b.c_str()) > 0);
}
template <> bool Vector<char*>::my_compare(const char* a, const char* b){
  return (strcmp(a, b) > 0);
}
```

The specialization works for Mystring but not for char*. I get the following error:

```
iterator.cpp:106:18: error: template-id ‘my_compare<>’ for ‘bool Vector<char*>::my_compare(const char*, const char*)’ does not match any template declaration
 template <> bool Vector<char*>::my_compare(const char* a, const char* b){
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The compiler spits the same error when I use different pointer types, like int* or Mystring*. I am using G++ as the compiler. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong and how I can fix it? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What if I actually want to compare if a pointer value is less than another?  Your `Vector` class does too much hand-holding for the user.  Instead supply a custom function to do the comparison, similar to `std::sort`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I agree with you but this is part of a coding assignment. I want to understand why this approach doesn't work for ```char*``` and how I could fix it.

Comment: *I agree with you, and I wouldn't do it this way normally but it's part of my assignment* -- Then the assignment is not well thought-out, TBH.  Assignment restrictions need to be posted, since it would be a waste of time posting an answer that shows the real-world way these things are done (the better solution would be to provide an overloaded `my_compare` function that takes a comparison predicate as the third argument).    Also please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little subtle, but it's because `const char*` is not the same as `char* const`.

Your function `my_compare(const T a, const T b)` expects a `const T`. `T` in this case is `char*`. So you want a *constant pointer* not a *pointer to a constant*.

The rules for adding qualifiers allow you to put `const` and `volatile` to the left of the type, even though most modifiers are applied right to left. To put another, you are defining:

```
my_compare(char const* a, char const* b)
```

Instead of:

```
my_compare(char* const a, char* const b)
```

Some other references to see:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const_(computer_programming)

> When reading to the left, it is important that you read the elements from right to left. So an `int const *` becomes a pointer to a const int and not a const pointer to an int.

Comment: @Jhappy77 You should be able to accept an answer if it works for you.